# Получить заголовок HTML страницы БЕЗ сторонних бибилиотек(HtmlAgiliyPack)

Tags: c#, .net

Нужно запарстить веб-сайт и получить оттуда html код,после этого нужно достать оттуда title, используя пример отсюда https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Создание [дубликатов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1379230/373567) делу не поможет. _Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу_

Comment: @aepot Тебе че так сложно помочь или как?

Comment: Я уже все перепробовал,без сторонних библиотек ничего у меня не выходит

Comment: А мне именно нужно БЕЗ них

Comment: Мне не сложно. В прошлом вопросе вы показали код получения данных по http, нормальный между прочим, я подсказал, как получить `string` из этого. И как дальше поступить с html. На блюдечке, можно сказать. А вы опять за свое, только в этот раз даже код не показали. В чем именно проблема то? Чем помочь?

Comment: Я же говорю,мне нужно без сторонних библиотек на чистом HttpClient и C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В лоб, так в лоб. Заголовок находится в теге `<title>`.

```
using HttpClient client = new();
string html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
string title;
if (html.Contains("<title>"))
{
    title = html.Substring(html.IndexOf("<title>") + 7);
    title = title.Remove(title.IndexOf("</title>")).Trim();
}
else
    title = "<заголовок не найден>";
```

`title` - заголовок.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: startIndex
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex)
   at ConsoleApp5.Program.<Main>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Matsenko\source\repos\ConsoleApp5\ConsoleApp5\Program.cs:line 21
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

Comment: @Matsenko это значит, что заголовка у этой страницы нет. Дополнил код.

Comment: все там есть,код неправильный

Comment: @Matsenko1 как именно вы это поняли?

Comment: Попробуй взять любой сайт начиная от Гугла до Амазона

Comment: @Matsenko1 и? В строке `html` что? Точка останова, отладка, пошаговое выполнение, не?

Comment: В строке html точка останова

Comment: @Matsenko1 вы очень смешное написали, уделите пару минут чтению вот этого: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019 там с анимированными картинками даже.

Comment: Понял,спасибо всего доброго ,туплю под вечер

Comment: @aepot, у тебя опечатка в строке: `title = html.Substring(html.IndexOf("<title>" + 7));`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, скобкой промахнулся. Коварная конкатенация. :)

Comment: @aepot, кстати, поэтому и была ошибка в первом комментарии

Comment: @Matsenko1 заработало?

Comment: @aepot Как часы)